# Runtime Error: Return vector of pointers as reference

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am trying to solve Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP), and it seems to work as long as no value is returned to the calling function. I have tried returning vector, array, array and vector of pointers, however nothing seems to work. In fact, some of the previously declared and properly functioning vectors do not work either. I am using GCC on Windows 64-bit platform, and the error appears during runtime at `vector<int> tabout = Ridesharing::CVRP(Vertex, X, Y, Demand);`

__gnu_cxx::new_allocator::deallocate(this=0x22db20, __p=0x9a90e0) (C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:110)

```
  ~vector() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { std::_Destroy(this->_M_impl._M_start, this->_M_impl._M_finish,
          _M_get_Tp_allocator()); }

// LEADING UP TO...  
// __p is not permitted to be a null pointer.
  void
  deallocate(pointer __p, size_type)
  { ::operator delete(__p); }
```

Formal declaration of variables

```
struct Vertex{
    int id;
    double x;
    double y;
    double demand;
};
vector<int> *tabout;                     //Output
int vertex_num;                         
int capacity;                                           
int verify = 0;                         
vector<Vertex> vertex;                         
vector<vector<int> > population; 
//int** population;                     //Set of solutions in the population
double cur_best_distance;               
vector<int> cur_best_individual;        
double best_solution;

vector<int>
Ride::CVRP(vector<int> id, vector<double> x, vector<double> y, vector<double> demand)
{
    vertex_num = id.size()-1;
    capacity = 8;
    best_solution = 99999999;
    population.resize(pop_size, vector<int>(vertex_num));
    best_individual = new int[vertex_num];
    vertex.resize(vertex_num);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= vertex_num; i++){
        vertex[i].id = id[i];
        vertex[i].x = x[i];
        vertex[i].y = y[i];
        vertex[i].demand = demand[i];
    }

    initialize_population();

    int generation = 1;

    while (generation < max_generation){

        choose_individuals(best_individual);

        individuals_transform();

        //cout <<"the best in current generation: "<<cur_best_distance<< endl;
        generation ++;
    }
// COUT RESULTS IN RUNTIME ERROR AT THIS LINE!
    printf("The cost of the best solution is: %0.3f", best_solution);       
if (verify == 1)
        cout << "\nThe optimal route is visited in the following order: ";


        vector <int> result = final_solution(best_individual);

        tabout = new vector<int>(result.size());
        vector<int> &temp = *tabout; //Create a reference
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
            temp[i] = result[i]; // SET OF VERTEX VISITED AS OUTPUT
    cout << temp[i]<<" ";
}
    cout << endl;
if(verify == 0)
    cout<<"\nNo feasible solution found"<<endl;

delete[] best_individual;
best_individual = NULL;
//  system("pause");
    return temp; // VECTOR SUCCESSFULLY RETURNED AS REFERENCE
}
```

Calling function:

```
void main();
{

vector<int> tabout = Ridesharing::CVRP(Vertex, X, Y, Demand); // RUNTIME ERROR AT THIS LINE, HOWEVER DEBUG SHOWS `tabout` with assigned values from `temp`
            std::vector<std::vector<int>> taborder(0, std::vector<int>(tabout.size())); // Defaults to zero initial value
            for(unsigned i =0; i < tabout.size(); i++){
                cout<<tabout[i]<<" ";
                taborder[0][i] = tabout[i];
            }
            delete &tabout; //Delete the reference
            cout<<endl;
            for (unsigned s = 0; s < taborder.size(); s++)
                for (unsigned m = 0; m < taborder[s].size(); m++)
                    cout<<Vertex[taborder[s][m]]<< " ";
            cout<<endl;
}
```

It has been a frustrating experience trying several implementation strategies to get past this runtime error, however nothing seems to have worked. Why would `cout` not work? I can't identify the source of this undefined behavior, but every error seems to be related to stl_vector.h.

Comment: `vector<int> tabout` is in automatic storage, so `delete &tabout;` is a very bad idea.

Comment: @user4581301 I had to since I used `tabout = new vector<int>(result.size());` Anyway, I have removed all this to use vector of objects instead of pointers. @1201ProgramAlarm suggestion coupled with minor tweaks resolved this issue.

Comment: Kind of figured it was a holdover. Didn't make enough sense in context with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing past the bounds of your allocated arrays.  You allocate space for `vertex_num` elements in `vertex`, which are numbered `0` to `vertex_num-1`.  You initialization loop (`for (unsigned i = 0; i <= vertex_num; i++)`) will access `vertex[vertex_num]`, writing past the end of the array resulting in Undefined Behavior (and clobbering other memory).

You need to either allocate one more element in `vertex` or use `i < vertex_num` in your loops.

Comment: Modified `vertex.resize(vertex_num+1);`, but nothing changed.

Comment: Fixed it. `std::vector<std::vector<int>> taborder(0, std::vector<int>(tabout.size()));` initializes size 0 as opposed to a 2d vector of size > 1. Also, changed `vertex.resize(vertex_num)` to `vertex.resize(vertex_num + 1)` as you suggested.

Comment: I would strongly recommend _GLIBCXX_DEBUG to catch more errors associated with STL containers.